# Unknown column 'stockout_details.purchi' in 'on clause'

Tags: php, sql

i'm using this query but i found this error Unknown column 'stockout_details.purchi' in 'on clause'

```
SELECT sale_nag,stockin_details.purchi,
       COALESCE(stockin_details.sale_nag,0) + stockin_details.sale_nag   result
FROM stockin_details LEFT JOIN 
     (SELECT SUM(sale_nag) AS snag
      FROM stockout_details
      WHERE purchi='a12'
      GROUP BY marka,chalan,room,rack
     ) stockout_details
     ON stockin_details.purchi=stockout_details.purchi
WHERE stockin_details.purchi='a12'
GROUP BY marka,chalan,room,rack
```

Comment: (1) I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Please tag only the database that you are using.  (2) What part of the error message do you now understand?  It seems quite clear.  The column is not in the subquery.

Comment: I know dear there is all clear but why I'm facing this error

Comment: Hello and welcome! It looks like the schema of the table is missing the column you requested. Can you share the definition of the tables used?

Comment: That GROUP BY in invalid and should raise an exception. You typically GROUP BY the same columns as you SELECT, except those who are arguments to set functions.

Comment: Also, why GROUP BY without any set functions?

Comment: thanks dear @GordonLinoff i just missed to define name of colume

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to include the column in the subquery:

```
SELECT o.sale_nag, i.purchi,
       COALESCE(i.sale_nag,0) + i.sale_nag   result
FROM stockin_details i LEFT JOIN 
     (SELECT purchi, SUM(sale_nag) AS snag
      FROM stockout_details
      WHERE purchi = 'a12'
      GROUP BY marka, chalan, room, rack, purchi
     ) o
     ON i.purchi = o.purchi
WHERE i.purchi = 'a12'
GROUP BY i.marka, i.chalan, i.room, i.rack;
```

Note that I replaced the table aliases with more manageable aliases and qualified all column names.

That said, I'd be surprised if the query actually did anything useful -- the `result` is only using values from one table.

Also, I would expect the `join` conditions to use *all* the columns in the aggregation.  If you want further help with the query, ask a *new* question.  Provide sample data, desired results, an explanation of what the code should do, and an appropriate database tag.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include column stockout_details.purchi in your select then only you can use it in join clause as you are creating subquery and this is what Gordon was trying to highlight.